# What is the correct Ashkenaz nusach for the bracha of hamapil?

Tags: shema

When I google the Hamapil bracha to say at night, the version I always come upon is this:
https://www.tefillos.com/krias_shema.asp

In my Artscroll siddur, the nusach is different, as the words before the 'Yehi Ratzon' are moved to the end and worded a bit different.

Does anyone know what the correct or accepted nusach is for Ashkenaz?

Comment: Apparently there are variations, so how do you expect us to evaluate which is "correct"?

Comment: There are so many debates even among _ashkenazim._ It really depends on your origins and the authority you accept. There is an issue, whether to place the blessing in the beginning or in the end, whether to say כי אתה המאיר לאישון בת עין or not, to use cholam in הרהורים or not, and so on...